# Office365 management API - Unable to subscribe

Tags: azure, office365api, azure-management-api, office365-rest-client

I want to capture the file operation events in OneDrive. So I created a tenant in azure and attached an App with it. I provided the necessary permissions to the app.

I am able to get the access token using the client key, secret created in portal.azure.com. This means that tenant, app and client secret is correct.

Now I am using Office365 management API to subscribe to the content type Audit.SharePoint but in response I get this message,

```
{'error': {'code': 'AF10001', 'message': 
'The permission set () sent in the request does not include the expected permission.'}}
```

Can anybody help ?

Note: I am using free account. I am wondering if this error is coming because its a free account.

==============================================================
After updating the Azure AD license to P2. It could further but subscription still failed with following error.

```
{'error': {'code': 'StartSubscription [CorrId=a2c6111b-7908-486b-ab69-9f6ccac7679e][TenantId=9cef4c36-5f08-49c4-9f61-7d4a7860444c,ContentType=Audit.SharePoint,ApplicationId=13d763cd-abbc-456d-96e3-57af430f025f,PublisherId=46b472a7-c68e-4adf-8ade-3db49497518e]
[AppId', 'message': '3d763cd-abbc-456d-96e3-57af430f025f] failed. Exception: 
Microsoft.Office.Compliance.Audit.DataServiceException: Tenant 9cef4c36-5f08-49c4-9f61-7d4a7860444c does not exist.\r\n   
at Microsoft.Office.Compliance.Audit.API.AzureManager.

<GetSubscriptionTableClientForTenantAsync>d__52.MoveNext() in 
d:\\dbs\\sh\\nibr\\0705_172037\\cmd\\2\\sources\\dev\\auditing\\src\\auditapiservice\\common\\AzureManager.cs:line 2116\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown 
---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Office.Compliance.Audit.API.AzureManager.<GetAPISubscriptionAsync>d__22.MoveNext() in 
d:\\dbs\\sh\\nibr\\0705_172037\\cmd\\2\\sources\\dev\\auditing\\src\\auditapiservice\\common\\AzureManager.cs:line 550\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n  
 at Microsoft.Office.Compliance.Audit.API.StartController.<StartSubscription>d__0.MoveNext() in d:\\dbs\\sh\\nibr\\0705_172037\\cmd\\1\\sources\\dev\\auditing\\src\\auditapiservice\\apifrontendservicerole\\Controllers\\StartController.cs:line 76'}}
```

====================================================
MS Support told to have atleast one license of exchange online. So I started basic trial version of Office 365 for two users in AD.
With this, I was able to start auditing for users/admins from compliance.microsoft.com
But on hitting the subscription API, I get following error.

"error":{"code":"StartSubscription [CorrId=0a7a9c46-012c-4510-aff6-888a840a74f6][TenantId=9cef4c36-5f08-49c4-9f61-7d4a7860444c,ContentType=Audit.SharePoint,ApplicationId=13d763cd-abbc-456d-96e3-57af430f025f,PublisherId=46b472a7-c68e-4adf-8ade-3db49497518e][AppId","message":"3d763cd-abbc-456d-96e3-57af430f025f] failed. Exception: Microsoft.Office.Compliance.Audit.DataServiceException: Tenant 9cef4c36-5f08-49c4-9f61-7d4a7860444c does not exist.\r\n   at Microsoft.Office.Compliance.Audit.API.AzureManager.d__52.MoveNext() in d:\\dbs\\sh\\nibr\\0712_070108\\cmd\\y\\sources\\dev\\auditing\\src\\auditapiservice\\common\\AzureManager.cs:line 2116\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Office.Compliance.Audit.API.AzureManager.d__22.MoveNext() in d:\\dbs\\sh\\nibr\\0712_070108\\cmd\\y\\sources\\dev\\auditing\\src\\auditapiservice\\common\\AzureManager.cs:line 550\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Office.Compliance.Audit.API.StartController.d__0.MoveNext() in d:\\dbs\\sh\\nibr\\0712_070108\\cmd\\6\\sources\\dev\\auditing\\src\\auditapiservice\\apifrontendservicerole\\Controllers\\StartController.cs:line 76"}}

Answer (score 1):

> Note: I am using free account. I am wondering if this error is coming because its a free account.

According to [ehowardl3](https://community.splunk.com/t5/Reporting/o365-Configuration/m-p/454843):

- Check Azure Active Directory licensing level, [Azure Active Directory licensing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/) requires either a Premium P1 or Premium P2 license to be able to pull event information through the Office 365 Management API. **Microsoft does not grant permission to use the API to enable subscriptions for Free or Basic licensing options.**

> {'error': {'code': 'AF10001', 'message':
> 'The permission set () sent in the request does not include the expected permission.'}}

Once you get the required license, to resolve above error, according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-reference):

- `AF10001`: The permission set ({0}) sent in the request did not include the expected permission `ActivityFeed.Read`.

So, make sure to grant `ActivityFeed.Read` permission in [Azure Active Directory](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/dsm?topic=mo3-configuring-microsoft-office-365-account-in-microsoft-azure-active-directory)

**Updated answer:**

> Microsoft.Office.Compliance.Audit.DataServiceException: Tenant *** does not exist

To resolve above mentioned exception, according to [markjjo](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-365-management-api/issues/89):

- Make sure that unified auditing is enabled for your Office 365 organization, as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/turn-audit-log-search-on-or-off?view=o365-worldwide), try the following PowerShell command:

```
Set-AdminAuditLogConfig -UnifiedAuditLogIngestionEnabled $true
```

References: [Office 365 Management API - Postman sample](https://www.postman.com/tlingenfelder/workspace/tlingenfelder-s-public-workspace/documentation/8229827-2f286df4-9b2d-48d3-be17-ad880d8d5f2d) and [Can not connect with office 365](https://groups.google.com/g/wazuh/c/CHHVuHBbum0)

Comment: Thanks. with the P2 trial license, It could go further. But on starting subscription, it gives followign error updated in the main question.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to enable audit logs from compliance manager. But on clicking 'start recording user/admin activity', it gives the error that 'Sorry! We couldn't update your organization settings. Please try again.'

Comment: After one hour of adding the global administrator role, it gives following error on trying to start recording user/admin activity. 'Substrate Only Agent': 'Organization "neelammishra603gmail.onmicrosoft.com" is not licensed for Exchange email functionality.

Comment: [Unable to turn on Audit Logging](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/microsoft-365-docs/issues/1112), [Create a support ticket](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/) and [Get support for Microsoft 365 for business](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide)

Comment: MS support told that atleast one exchange license is required. So I enrolled for free trial of Office365 and assigned license to two users in AD. After this I enabled auditing in compliance.microsoft.com. But now still I get this exception (question updated) on hitting subscription API.

Comment: Its confirmed that issue has been resolved. It just took some time to percolate thru.